# Словосочетание числительное+местоимение+существительное. Как склонять

Tags: числительные

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, правильно ли согласованы числительное и существительное в предложении:
Сервис помог более 350 Ваших коллег.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: ***Сервис помог более  чем 350 Вашим коллегам.***

1. Из Справочника по пунктуации

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68

(НЕ) БОЛЕЕ / БОЛЬШЕ, ЧЕМ, в составе сравнительного оборота

При отсутствии сравниваемых понятий слова «(не) более / больше чем» образуют с последующими словами **неразложимое сочетание** (единый член предложения).   *Деревня была уже **не более чем** в двухстах шагах…*

2. Таким образом, из этого примера мы видим, что сочетание  "более чем" **не участвует в управлении и его можно опустить**, если числовой оборот имеет форму косвенных падежей (не И.п. и В.п.).

Проверка: Сервис помог (кому) 350 вашим коллегам /более чем 350 вашим коллегам.

Сервис помог (кому?) пяти вашим коллегам/более чем пяти вашим коллегам. Здесь **согласование** числительного, местоимения и существительного в Д.п.

3. **Дополнение** (для счетного оборота в форме И.п. и В.п.)

В этом случае может использоваться форма "более/не более".

Сравнить: Глубина моря здесь пять-шесть метров (И.п). Мы могли подождать пять минут (В.п.).

Глубина моря здесь была **не более (чего?)  пяти-шести метров**. [Фазиль Искандер. (1980-1990)]. Мы могли, конечно, подождать, но **не более пяти минут.** [Алексей Моторов.  (2013)].

Форма "более/не более"  задает существительному Р.п., если числовой оборот имеет форму И.п. или В.п.